# In a circuit with the TI TPS61165, how was D2 chosen?

Tags: integrated-circuit, datasheet, component-selection, circuit-design, led-driver

Looking at datasheet for the [TPS61165](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61165-q1.pdf), I don't see how they chose D2 - it looks like it will only work if the voltage supply is above 12v due to this diode, but the chip's input range is 3-18v. I would like to know if I can replace it with say a 9v diode, could I use a 10-15v range for powering it, or should I stick to the 12v, even if my supply voltage drops below it?

[image: reference circuit]

Comment: Ignacio answered your question, but if you go section 8.1 in the datasheet... "8.1 Application Information
The TPS61165-Q1 device drives 6 high-brightness LEDs; the LED current is set at 350 mA. A 12-V Zener diode is used to clamp the input voltage, which makes the TPS61165-Q1 device suitable for car battery supply applications." It's also mentioned in there :)

Comment: Should be quite safe to use the existing diode with a 9V supply. It just won't have to do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The datasheet you link to is for the -Q1 grade device, which is qualified for automotive applications. At times, e.g. when cranking the engine, the supply voltage can go *well* above 12V, therefore we must have some sort of protection for the IC since it can only safely handle 20V on its supply input. This is sometimes referred to as 'load-dumping' -- [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva681a/snva681a.pdf) is an application note (also from TI) that explains why it happens.

If you are certain to never see transients above 18V then you can omit D2 entirely and tie the supply input pin directly to the supply.

Comment: Would I omit the entire R1/C4/C2 section, parallel C1 and C4, or do I still need a resistor there to limit the current

Comment: @user2813274: R1's primary purpose is to keep D2 from melting down. As long as the supply can handle the surges of current being pulled by L1 you should also be able to remove C4 and replace R1 with a short.

Comment: @user2813274  If you are sure that the power supply voltage will never exceed 18V, then you can omit D2 and R1, and wire Vin directly to the Vbat rail.  I would keep C4 (even though it's in parallel with C1) and place C4 close to the Vin pin.

Answer (score 3):

Short version: yes, 9V Zener would do alright.

In the O.P. schematic D2, C4, R1 form a crude 12V shunt regulator.  It can be any voltage in the acceptable Vin range from 3V to 18V (as the O.P. have already noticed).  It can be any sort of voltage source.

Try to keep the Vin voltage high, because it's the voltage that drives the gate of the N-channel MOSFET switch (see block diagram on [p.8 of the datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61165-q1.pdf#8)).  If the MOSFET gate is driven with a low voltage, the efficiency begins to suffer.  9V results in an decent efficiency, as visible from the chart.

[image]